# Example on how to force a re render of a Nav Bar Component in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The issue I am currently facing is that when I log into my app, the NavBar component is not re-rendering to show buttons that only a logged in user can see.
I have to manually refresh my browser which forces the NavBar component to re-render, thereby showing the buttons.

Any idea on how best to accomplish this issue?

I have provided my App.js and NavBar components below

Here is my App.js:

```
import './App.css';

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  // Link, not used yet, commented out for now to remove warning
  Redirect,
  Switch
} from "react-router-dom";

import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';

import LandingPage from "./pages/LandingPage";
import RegisterPage from "./pages/RegisterPage";
import ProfilePage from "./pages/ProfilePage";
import CreateEventPage from "./pages/CreateEventPage";
import EventProfilePage from "./pages/EventProfilePage";
import NotFoundPage from "./pages/NotFoundPage";
import UnsponsoredEventsPage from "./pages/UnsponsoredEventsPage";
import EventsNextWeekPage from "./pages/EventsNextWeekPage";
import EventsByCategoryPage from "./pages/EventsByCategoryPage";

import Auth from "./utils/Auth";
import EventsLandingPage from "./pages/EventsLandingPage";
import LoginPage from "./pages/LoginPage";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    Auth.loggedIn() === true
    ? <Component {...props} />
    : <Redirect to="/login" />
  )}/>
);

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
          <Route exact path="/register" component={RegisterPage} />
          <Route exact path="/unsponsored" component={UnsponsoredEventsPage} />
          <Route exact path="/nextweek" component={EventsNextWeekPage} />
          <Route exact path="/category" component={EventsByCategoryPage} />
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/event" component={EventProfilePage} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/profile/:id" component={ProfilePage} />
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/createevent" component={CreateEventPage} />
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/events" component={EventsLandingPage} />
          <Route path="/event/:id" component={EventProfilePage} />
          <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>

  );
}

export default App;
```

And here is my NavBar component code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Menu } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Auth from "../../utils/Auth";
import './NavBar.css'

let userID = "";

if (Auth.loggedIn()) {
  userID = Auth.getProfile().id
}

const profileLink = `/profile/${userID}`

export default class NavBar extends Component {
  state = {
    activeItem: "",
    isLoggedIn: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (Auth.loggedIn()) {
      this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true })
    }
  }

  logout() {
    Auth.logout()
  }

  handleNavClick = (event, { name }) => {
    this.setState({ activeItem: { name }.name })
  };

  render() {
    const { activePage } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Menu inverted>
          <Menu.Item
            as={Link}
            to="/"
            key="home"
            name="home"
            active={this.state.activeItem === 'home'}
            onClick={this.handleNavClick}
          />
          <Menu.Item
            as={Link}
            to="/unsponsored"
            key="browse events"
            name="browse events"
            active={this.state.activeItem === 'browse events'}
            onClick={this.handleNavClick}
          />
          {this.state.isLoggedIn ? (
            <Menu.Item
              as={Link}
              to="/createevent"
              key="create event"
              name="create event"
              active={this.state.activeItem === 'create event'}
              onClick={this.handleNavClick}
            />
          ) : (
              <div />
            )}

          <Menu.Menu position='right'>
            {this.state.isLoggedIn ? (
              <Menu.Item
                as={Link}
                to={profileLink}
                key="profile"
                name="profile"
                active={this.state.activeItem === 'profile'}
                onClick={this.handleNavClick}
              />
            ) : (
                <div />
              )}

            {this.state.isLoggedIn ? (
              <Menu.Item
                href="/"
                name="logout"
                active={this.state.activeItem === 'logout'}
                onClick={this.logout}
              />
            ) : (
                <Menu.Item
                  href="/login"
                  name="login"
                  active={this.state.activeItem === 'login'}
                  onClick={this.handleNavClick}
                />
              )}
          </Menu.Menu>
        </Menu>
      </div>
    );
  };
};
```

Comment: Could you share the code from your `Auth` object?

Comment: I don't have a problem sharing it, but  I don't see how that could help @Rallen

Comment: It might help finding a solution.